# AttributeError when trying to use the pygame.Rect.scale_by() method

Tags: python, pygame

Python script:

```py
import pygame
left, top, width, height = 0, 0, 1, 1
my_rect = pygame.Rect(left, top, width, height)
my_rect.scale_by(2)
```

Result in terminal:

```terminal
pygame 2.2.0 (SDL 2.0.22, Python 3.8.8)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'pygame.rect.Rect' object has no attribute 'scale_by'
```

According to the documentation, `scale_by()` is a method of `pygame.Rect`: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.scale_by

> scale_by()
>
> scale the rectangle by given a multiplier
>
> scale_by(scalar) -> Rect
>
> scale_by(scalex, scaley) -> Rect
>
> Returns a new rectangle with the size scaled by the given multipliers. The rectangle remains centered around its current center. A single scalar or separate width and height scalars are allowed. Values above one will increase the size of the rectangle, whereas values between zero and one will decrease the size of the rectangle.

Why am I getting this error ? How can I make the `scale_by()` method work ?

Other methods like `move()` works perfectly fine in this context, but some like `scale_by()` does not and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scale_by` is implemented in Pygame 2.3.0 (see the release notes [pygame 2.3.0](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/releases/tag/2.3.0)). You have to do 2 things:

1. upgrade to Pygame 2.3.0

   ```
   pip install pygame --upgrade
   ```
2. use [`scale_by_ip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.scale_by_ip) instead of [`scale_by`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.scale_by)

   ```py
   my_rect.scale_by_ip(2)
   ```

   or assign the return value of `scale_by` to `my_rect`

   ```py
   my_rect = my_rect.scale_by(2)
   ```

   Note, `scale_by` doesn't scale the rectangle itselfe, but returns a new rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was only added in pygame v2.3.0.

It doesn't say that in the documentation but I got an AttributeError in versions 2.0.3, 2.1.3 and 2.2.0 and it worked fine in 2.3.0.

So just upgrade to the latest pygame.